# How to insert each array item into each object of other array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 arrays

I want this:

```
[{name: 'Sweater', qty: 1}, {name: 'Skirt', qty: 3}, {name: 'Socks', qty: 2}]
```

but I get

```js
    qtyList = [1, 3, 2]
    data = [{name: 'Sweater', qty: 1}, {name: 'Skirt', qty: 1}, {name: 'Socks', qty: 1}]

    let assignQty = data.map((x, id) => {
            qtyList.map((y, idx) => {
                if (idx == id) return x.qty = y
            })
        })
        console.log('assignQty', assignQty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially zipping the 2 lists together - typically done as follows:

```js
const qtyList = [1, 3, 2]
const data = [{name: 'Sweater', qty: 1}, {name: 'Skirt', qty: 1}, {name: 'Socks', qty: 1}]

const result = data.map((item,idx) => ({...item, qty: qtyList[idx]}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const qtyList = [1, 3, 2];


data = [{name: 'Sweater', qty: 1}, {name: 'Skirt', qty: 1}, {name: 'Socks', qty: 1}]



const updateQuantity = (list, data) => {
  if (data.length !== list.length) {
    return
  }


  for (let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    const element = list[index];

    // udpate data
    data[index] = {
      name: data[index].name,
      qty: element
    }
  }
 

  return data;

}


console.log(updateQuantity(qtyList, data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Spread syntax` on `item` than change `qty` with array values

```js
qtyList = [1, 3, 2]

data = [{name: 'Sweater', qty: 1}, {name: 'Skirt', qty: 1}, {name: 'Socks', qty: 1}]

let assignQty = data.map((item, index) => (
                 {
                   ...item,
                   qty: qtyList[index]}
                ));

console.log("assignQty", assignQty );
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the spread operator, update the required field and then return `x`.

```js
    qtyList = [1, 3, 2]
    data = [{name: 'Sweater', qty: 1}, {name: 'Skirt', qty: 1}, {name: 'Socks', qty: 1}]

    var assignQty = data.map((x, id) => {x.qty=qtyList[id];return x;})

    console.log('assignQty', assignQty)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to your question. In your example, you were trying to map two arrays into one. This approach "loops" the data array containing the objects you want to change.

Using the index of each object it sets the `item.qty` to the value in `qtyList[index]`.

```js
    qtyList = [1, 3, 2];
    data = [{
      name: 'Sweater',
      qty: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Skirt',
      qty: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Socks',
      qty: 1
    }];

    let assignQty = data.map((item, index) => {
      item.qty = qtyList[index];
      return item;
    });
    console.log(assignQty)
```